# Sprites not displaying how I want them to display

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, sfml

I was making an SFML game, and I wanted to limit the number of bullets that can exist on the screen at the same time to 5 for now.

This is the minimal code needed:

```
#define max_bullets_displayed 5

//...

Bullet* pociski[max_bullets_displayed];

//...

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    pociski[i] = 0;
}

//...

//creating bullets when needed
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (pociski[i] == 0)
        {
            pociski[i] = new Bullet("pocisk.png", sf::Mouse::getPosition().x, sf::Mouse::getPosition().y, 23, 20);
        }
    }
}

//...

//displaying
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (pociski[i] != 0) window.draw(pociski[i]->sprite);
}
```

I think there is something wrong with the pointers. Only one of the bullets can be displayed, the rest doesn't display even after clicking. No exceptions are thrown, and the memory is fine.

Comment: First of all, you have a memory leak. You need to delete the objects you created with `new`. Other then that pleas clairfy what is you problem exactly. What is wrong and what did you expect?

Comment: I don't need to delete the objects created with new for now, because I limited them only to 5 maximum, and also the objects will be deleted whenever the bullet hits something. @K.Kirsz

Comment: Ok, You spawn all the bullets in the same posistion, right? Aren't they just drawn on top of each other?

Comment: Oh, thanks, I just realized it.

Answer (score 0):

All the bullets are spawned in the same position, so they are drawn on top of each other.

```
pociski[i] = new Bullet("pocisk.png", sf::Mouse::getPosition().x, sf::Mouse::getPosition().y, 23, 20);
```